# ES6 export extended class and then import it

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export

I have a basic class (mobile.js)

```
class Mobile {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }
    method(msg){
       ...
    }
}
module.exports = Mobile;
```

Then I import it to (mobileextended.js);

```
import Mobile from './mobile';

 class MobilePhone extends Mobile {
     method(){
        super.method('hello world!');
     }   
}
module.exports = MobilePhone;
```

And in the end I want to import it to mobilephone.js:

```
 import MobilePhone from './mobileextended.js';

    MobilePhone.method();
```

How can I make that work in ES6 style? Because now I'm getting Cannot read property 'open' of undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to name things in the palce you import them, such as

```
import Mobile from './Mobile'
```

you should use a default export, such as

```
export default Mobile
```

from the place where `Mobile` is defined.

---

Compare this with having a named export

```
export class Mobile { ... }
```

and importing that specific name in a separate module.

```
import {Mobile} from Mobile
```

---

However, as pointed out by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) in the comments, this is not the source of your error. To use a non-static method, you need to create an instance of that class.

```
const mobilePhone = new MobilePhone()
mobilePhone.method()
```

Comment: They are also never instantiating the class.

Comment: Whops, wasn't paying attention to the actual code, only the question. Added the remark. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution but I got ERROR: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined instead. Can you please write the code the way it should be written in ES6 so I could get familiar with it?

Comment: Ok I got it now running, there was a mistake I have made. The named export approach is something i need to study further, because that way I guess I could export several classes fro the same module.